# subtle crypto with ECDSA : Cannot create a key using the specified key usages

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ecdsa, jose

I wanted to import an ECDSA private key in Chrome to sign some data, tried yet with `crypto.subtle.importKey`: feeded the `importKey` with a derivated private key using `secp256k1`.

When trying to use the lib, I got stuck with the following error:
`Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.`

The code:

```js
const browserKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    derivatedNode.privateKey, // ArrayBuffer
    {
        name: 'ECDSA',
        namedCurve: 'P-256' // Haven't found better fit for secp256k1?
    },
    false,
    ['sign']
);
```

Double-checked my private key, got `Uint8Array(32)` which seems to be usually OK with `importKey`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Cryptography API does not support the `secp256k1` curve. It will also [not support](https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/issues/82#issuecomment-849856773) it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Web Crypto API doesn't support secp256k1 but you can use two workarounds:

1. Use a Node.js library to store the private key, and issue from the browser requests to sign some payloads: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecdh-crypto/v/1.0.5
2. Use ethers.js library to do it in pure Javascript, but you won't be able to have non-extractable keys, this is good if you're building a browser extension with static bundle files, otherwise you have to trust your own servers not to get compromised: https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-wallet.html#signing